# Facebook friend invitation request doesn't display the message

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, android-facebook

I have a `String message = "hi";` and when the user gets the invitation he doesn't see my message, but something like `you have a request from ...`

```
params.putString("message", message);
params.putString("to", "123123123");
WebDialog webdialog = new WebDialog.Builder(PurchaseFlowActivity.this,
        Session.getActiveSession(), action, params)
        .setOnCompleteListener(new WebDialog.OnCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                    FacebookException error) {

            }
        }).build();
Window dialog_window = progressDialog.getWindow();
dialog_window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
webdialog.show();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message is not shown in the notification popup for *invites*.

It is only shown if the target user has installed the app already.

Comment: Thanks just wanted to be sure.