# Facebook android SDK the message doesn't appear in the invitation and in the web

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I understand from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19319656/sending-facebook-app-invitations-using-android-sdk-doesnt-show-preview-messag) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19097609/facebook-friend-invitation-request-doesnt-display-the-message) that you don't see the message in the Facebook app invitations but I don't find any related information about this in Facebook documentation. Is this answer official or just a guess? 
My second problem / question is that my invitation sent find and the invitee can see the invitation only in the Facebook app but not in Facebook website, is this normal or am I doing something work, here the code for sending invitations.

```
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    bundle.putString("message", message);
    bundle.putString("app_id", applicationId);

    if (friendId != null) {
        bundle.putString("to", friendId);
    }

    bundle.putString("title", title);
    bundle.putString("filters", "app_non_users");

    WebDialog applicationInvitationDialog = new WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder(
            activity,
            ParseFacebookUtils.getSession(),
            bundle
    )
            .setOnCompleteListener(
                    new WebDialog.OnCompleteListener() {
                        /**
                         *
                         * @param bundle
                         * @param facebookException
                         */
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(Bundle bundle, FacebookException facebookException) {                                

                        }
                    }
            ).build();

    applicationInvitationDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone struggle with that I found the answer. First, I couldn't find in FB documentation about message doesn't appear in invitation ... but for the second problem I found the solution. You need to add Facebook App platform and add canvas URL and then the invitation will appear in the web interface too.